# Using custom publisher with RGBDSlam

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, kinect, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I plan to try RGBDSlam on a pre recorded data. For that I have written a publisher which reads my data from text files and publishes. However the result that I get is not very good and also I have seen that depth image seen on RGBDSlam is only black and white.

I am publishing:

- /camera/rgb/image_mono which is a grayscale image sent through cvbridge
- /camera/depth/image, which is a IPL_DEPTH_32F IplImage, filled with depth values (in meters) and again sent through cvbridge
- /camera/rgb/points which is generated as a vector of PointXYZRGB

The point cloud and mono image are ok, I can see them clearly in RGBDSlam, however seeing depth image as I have mentioned makes me suspect that I am missing something. Am I?

Thanks..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11103/using-custom-publisher-with-rgbdslam/) by [paul simmons](https://answers.ros.org/users/1027/paul-simmons/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-09-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The depth image *is* only black and white; the grayscale values map to depths. RGBDSlam also works with the grayscale version of the RGB image (because that's what the visual feature library needs).

See [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/980/what-topics-is-my-nodelet-listening-to-for-rgbd6d) for some more details of what RGBDSlam expects as input.

Out of curiosity, why are you storing your data in text files, rather than using rosbag?

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2011-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1